# How to Execute Multiple Queries in a order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 26 queries to generate final output I want to automate the process and Execute all 26 queries one after another

how to execute all with a single click in the stepwise order

Comment: Write a Stored procedure and put them in a order.

Comment: I'm learning SQL server can you tell me how to put in order and how to write a stored procedure

Comment: I'd post your 26 queries so we can better understand the question. It is unclear if you want these returned as a single result (if it's even possible), or if your queries can be simplified (i'm betting on this, since you said you are learning SQL). So, you may have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) that we can help with.

Comment: @UrstruelyAnanth, See my answer and make your procedure like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a sample query only.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Your_Procedure_Name
AS 
BEGIN

    Write your First Query;

    Write your Second Query;

    Write your Third Query;

    .
    .
    .

    Write your Last Query;

END
```

And then execute the procedure using:

```
EXEC Your_Procedure_Name;
```

It will execute your queries in the above order.

Answer (score 1):

Schematic code follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC

AS

BEGIN

    <query 1> ;

    <query 2> ;

    <query 3> ;

    <query 4> ;

    <query 5> ;
    :
    :
END ;
```

Then:

```
EXEC ABC ;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You create a job in SQL Server Agent.  You then have basically two options:

- Put all the queries into a single script.
- Put each query into a separate job step.

Or some combination of the two.